# Prove/disprove: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(f(x))$ does not exist; and related question

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f$ be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$. Is each of the following claims true or false? If it is false, show it with a counterexample. If it is true, prove it directly from the formal definitions of a limit.
>
> - (a) IF $\lim _{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$, THEN $\lim _{x\to\infty} \sin (f(x))$ does not exist.
> - (b) IF $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=2$, THEN $\lim _{x\to\infty} f(\sin (x))$ does not exist.

[Original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKTJ8.png)

I think the (a) is false and the (b) is true just through intuition, but I can't seem to come up with an example for the first one or understand how to prove the second one using the definitions.

Comment: First one, simply let $f(x) =x$.  Or any function that increases without bound.

Comment: @AndrewChin if we want to prove it to be true then a) f needs to be arbitrary and we can't pick a function and b) we need to prove directly from the limits. I feel as though there is a counterexample for the first one but I just can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I am claiming that statement a) is false and am showing with a counterexample.

Comment: @AndrewChin did you misread the statement?

Comment: But in order to disprove it, we'd need to show that sin(f(x)) does exist as x approaches infinity. As far as I know, the limit of sin x as x approaches infinity DNE?

Comment: Let $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor *2\pi$.  Then $\lim f(x) \to \infty$ and $\lim \sin f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Oh I did misread the statement.

Comment: @fleablood spot on! what sort of thought process was there to come up with f(x)?

Comment: Sin x oscillates.  If $f$ is continuous then $\sin x$ will oscillate and have no limit.  But I *always* look for loopholes and unstated assumptions.  If $f$ is not continuous it can be that in only take values which just happen to be input so that the sins if those values converge.  Easiest would be if $\sin (f(x)) =c$ as constant which whould mean $f(x) = k + m*\pi$ for some fixed $k$ and integer $m$

Comment: The way you handle a question that's been answered is to *accept the answer*, not delete the question; part of the point here is that the questions themselves, together with their answers, form a resource for future readers (and save us having to type the same answer all over again).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ take the constant value $n\pi$ on $(n,n+1]$ for each $n$. Then $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ but $f(\sin x )\equiv 0$. So a) is false.

b) is true. Consider the points $x=\pi /2 +2n\pi$ and $x=-\pi /2 +2n\pi$ to see that $f(\sin x )$ cannot have a limit at $\infty$.

[ If possible let $f(\sin x) \to l$. Then there exists $T$ such that $|f(\sin x)-l| <\frac 1 2$ for all $x >T$. Put  $x=\pi /2 +2n\pi$ (with $n$ large enough to make $x >T$) to see that $|2-l| <\frac 1 2$ and put  $x=-\pi /2 +2n\pi$ (with $n$ large enough to make $x >T$) to see that $|0-l| <\frac 1 2$. It follows that $|2-0| \leq |2-l| +|l-0| <\frac  1 2+\frac 1 2=1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would you put part b in terms of epsilon and delta?

Comment: @adil.a I have added some details.